# What is occurring in the Render step in Miniprofiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler

Miniprofiler is showing me that the slowest part of my page is the "Render" step (attached screenshot below).

What is occurring in that Render step?  Is it the stage when your .aspx is converted into html to be sent to the client? Is there anywhere that I can add `Miniprofiler.Current.Step()` to see exactly why it is slow?

The app is MVC4 on .NET4.5 with the .aspx render engine.

[image]

EDIT:

The controller action is just standard MVC stuff along the lines of:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["foo"] = GetFoo();
    return View(model);
}
```

And the ASPX view is basic stuff like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p><% ViewData["foo"] %></p>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("Something", Model) %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I thought there were 2 partials from your Profiler. Clearly there isn't much here to Profile. But I would start by digging deeper into the **Something** Partial and the `GetFoo()` methods. Can you add their source? Let's see about setting more Profile points within each.

Answer (score 2):

First a `ViewResult` Object is generated when you call the `View()` Method.

This looks like

```
return View( Model );
```

Next the Render Step happens when the `ExecuteResult()` method is called in a `ViewResult` Object; Generating an **HTML** document that is sent to the client's browser.

**The ExecuteResult() Method (Render) process involves:**

- Rendering **HTML** elements and **JQuery**/**Javascript** attributes in place of your Helpers
- Model Binding to your View;; Each Helper and Model reference is replaced with Values from your Model and/or `ViewBag`.
- Merging your View with any layout
- Rendering your `Partials`

This last part, Rendering your ***Partials***, is like a recursive version of the creating the ***ViewResult*** Object. A `PartialView()`,  `RenderPartialView()`, or `Action()` Method is executed creating a **PartialViewResult** Object.  This new Result Object also has a `ExecuteResult()` method which generates an HTML "sub-document" to merge with the "Parent" **HTML** Document.

Partial View rendering takes even longer if the Partial View has a child **Action** (Controller Method) associated with it because it carries the burden of instantiating another controller...

You use 2 partial Views; The time to render the partial views combines to 16.1 ms out of 37.1 ms (43% of total time).

**Note about ASPX View Engine:**

I would bet that the **aspx** engine takes longer to render views than the **Razor** engine. 
The **aspx** engine

- has more content (much of it antiquated webforms remnants)
- I don't believe the ASPX engine has evolved since MVC 3 development began (late 2010), so it is probably less efficient.

---

**In Conclusion:**

Rendering Views (`ExecuteResult()`) can be fairly time consuming compared with **Route Engine** resoluton (4.5 ms) and **Controller** instantiation (7.3 ms).

In your case, the time to render your partials and parent views seems high. But I haven't used **mini-profiler** to check myself.

It could be that your **ASPX** View Engine is **THAT** inefficient, or you may have **Child** Actions associated with your partials that are making heavy database calls...

Comment: Thanks that's a good start.  Is there anywhere that Miniprofiler can be added to see what parts of this process are the worst?

Comment: @JK., good question. Can you add to your the source for your Index Action Method and View to your Post?